# How i can associate an SPFieldUser to a SPGroup

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, spfield, ssom, spfielduser

I am working on developing an event receiver inside my sharepoint 2013 farm on-premises.
and inside the event receiver i am trying to assign a list column to a SPGroup.

what i am trying to do is similar to the following steps using the UI:-

1. Go to a list settings.
2. click on the column at the list level.
3. override the column to be linked to a specific group (for example Approvers) instead of All Users as defined inside the site column level.
   [image]

Now here is my code inside the ER:-

```
SPGroup newgroup = site.RootWeb.SiteGroups[currentgroupname + " Members - " + curItemID.ToString()];
foreach (SPList splist in newSite.Lists)
 {
   if (splist.Title.ToLower() == "action")
       {
         SPFieldUser spfield = splist.Fields["ActionOwner"] as SPFieldUser;
         spfield =  newgroup as SPGroup;
       }
  }
```

But i am getting the following syntax error on this  `spfield =  newgroup as SPGroup;`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup'
>   to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUser'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
spfield.SelectionGroup = newgroup.ID;
spfield.Update();
spList.Update();
```

MSDN: [SPFieldUser.SelectionGroup property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.selectiongroup.aspx)

Sample: [Programmatically Set "Person Or Group" Column To Select User From A Specified Group](http://bhanuprakashbysani.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/programmatically-set-person-or-group.html)

Comment: thanks for the code,,, will try it ,, but i have a question ,, if i am modifying the list column at the list level using the code you provide,, then still i can override all the list columns if i update the column at the site level and chose to apply the changes to all the sub-sites ?? similar to doing things using the UI ???

Comment: I think is it possible. It is a site column?

Comment: it is a site column, and inside the code i want to override it inside the lists level... but i still like the option to have the control on overriding all the list columns by updating their parent site column.. now if i use the UI then i will have this option

Comment: You can use Update(true). From MSDN: Updates the database with changes that are made to the field and optionally propagates the changes to lists that implement the field. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454698.aspx

Comment: no i am asking different thing.. now i test at my end where using the code i assign the ActionOwner to the new group.. then i went to the site column and the chose to update the ActionOwner and propagate the change to all the list columns,, and the list column where changed from being assigned to the new group to be assigned to "All Users" as defined inside the site level.... so the code will update the list column as i am usng the UI ,, which is great..

Comment: OK. Yes. It is similar to doing things using the UI. But, to be sure make a test in dev o QA environment.